# Delete file by name from S3 using boto

Tags: django, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, boto

I am trying to delete a file by name from a django project. I have a function that correctly uploads the file but I cannot figure out the functionality. I have tried to use a examples with get_key and other functionality but have yet to be able to fetch the correct key. I think I am misusing get_key or it is depreciated. The files I am trying to delete are .png files as well, text refers to my file name and location. Below is a code snippet

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection, Bucket, Key
from boto.s3.key import Key

text = '//folder' + request.split(':')[1] + '_toS3.png'
conn = S3Connection('###', '####')
S3_BUCKET_NAME = 'Bucket_name'
b = Bucket(conn, S3_BUCKET_NAME)
k = Key(b)
k.key = k.get_key(text)
b.delete_key(k)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the bucket's [`delete_key`](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/s3.html#boto.s3.bucket.Bucket.delete_key) method. You provide `key_name` as an argument.

```
bucket = Bucket(conn, S3_BUCKET_NAME)
bucket.delete_key('path/to/key_name.png')
```

Comment: not sure why because I feel like this should work, but this does not work for me the file still remains in S3 and I know I have my path right.

Comment: Try `bucket.get_key('path/to/key_name.png')`. If that fails, then you are using the wrong key path. If it works, then perhaps your credentials do not have the permissions to delete the key.

Answer (score 0):

You've to change `k.key` to `k.name`.

```
b = Bucket(conn, S3_BUCKET_NAME)
k = Key(b)
k.name = k.get_key(text)
b.delete_key(k)
```

Comment: I still get 'Key' object has no attribute 'get_key' when I run this